# What image does Google Container Engine (GKE) use?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, google-kubernetes-engine

In the docs for GKE it says all nodes (currently) have the same VM instance.  Does this refer to the underlying machine type or the OS image (or both)?

I was assuming it was just the machine type (micro, small,.. etc) and Google layered their own image with infrastructure on top of that (e.g. kubernetes).

If this is the case what image does Google use on GKE?  I was thinking it may be CoreOS, since that would seem to be a good match, but I am not sure.

I'd like to set up staging machines with the same image as production... but perhaps we don't need to know this or it doesn't matter what is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All nodes in the cluster currently have the same machine type and OS image. By default, the machine type is n1-standard-1 and the image is a recent [container-vm image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms).

If you use gcloud to create your cluster, both settings can be overridden on the command line using the --machine-type and --source-image options respectively ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create)).

If you are using the cloud console to create your cluster, you can specify the machine type but not currently the source image.

Be aware that if you specify a different source image, you may not end up with a functional cluster because the kubernetes software that is installed on top of the source image requires specific underlying packages to be present in the system software. If you want consistency between staging/prod, you can use

```
gcloud container clusters describe <staging-cluster-name>
```

To see what image is being used in your staging cluster and ensure that you end up with the same image for your production cluster.

Comment: Thanks very much Robert for your very informative answer.  I am going to run the staging cluster on our site. Is there any reason why I shouldn't use the container-vm image locally? For example, if it is tied to some Google infrastructure?

Comment: How are you planning to run it at your site (I assume you mean on-premisis)? Virtual machines? Physical machines?

Comment: We plan to use physical servers (low-end PCs) for staging.  I am probably too focussed on consistency between staging and production.  I will try the Fedora(Ansible) Kubernetes install to start with and see how that goes (we are running Centos7).

Comment: The promise of containers is that you really shouldn't care about the underlying OS -- the container abstraction is the runtime environment that you want to be consistent between staging/prod and Docker provides that consistency.